Issues with transparencies in render mode
I reinstalled windows recently which meant I lost a lot of Blender settings. I'm working on a glass object, but I'm realizing that Blender won't really generate transparencies in cycles. I assume there is a setting I've forgotten about, but for the life of me I can't figure out what it might be.
Here's an image of what it's doing.

Here's an image of the suggested changes

Blend file


Your world is gray, your glass is gray. I think that's what transparency is, isn't it ?

No... it does the same with an HDMI background

so what does your scene look like if you put some plane under your cylinder with no materials? Can you show it in in your post?

I updated the image to show what I'm seeing. The background is an HDRI which I also cant see.

"I'm realizing that Blender won't really generate transparencies in cycles" Sorry, that is wrong. Maybe you are talking about EEVEE, but although it is a bit trickier to handle transparency and transmission than in Cycles, you can have transparency in EEVEE as well. So far we can only see your shader. There are a lot more settings which influence the result than just the shader (for example, the render settings themselves - haven't seen any of them yet). It would probably be best to pack all images into your file and upload it here https://blend-exchange.com and edit it in your question.

Why is it wrong? I'm referring to cycles, I guess I should have said the shaders aren't generating it?
The specific settings is what I'm after, after reinstalling Blender I can't recall every setting I had tweaked.
I added the blend file.
